# using the iniparser Linker error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'Ve download the [inparser library](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/) , and I'm trying to use the lib, by running its test program :

```
 gcc iniexqample.c -o o -liniparser.a
```

just like the documentation said. but I get this error:

```
     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liniparser.a     
collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've run  exactly the the installation steps , and  copied the the output file :

```
libparser.a
```

and

```
libiniparser.so.0
```

into    `usr/bin/`
I don't understand what the error message means, and how its possible to solve it .
any idea ?

By the way I'm using Ubuntu14.04

Comment: ld searches libraries in `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and maybe other places, but `/usr/bin` is very unlikely place for libraries. Also, you should use `-liniparser` (without `.a`).

Comment: you have `libparser.a` and you tried to link `-liniparser.a`.(see difference ) Also use  `-liniparser` and for this `liniparser.so` is necessary.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , I shouldn't use the .a